# linq query multiple levels deep

Tags: c#, xml, linq, select

Good day,

How can i query the following xml and for instance, return the policy and schedule names if the ResidenceIsSLP value == "No".

In addition, is this XML format/layout OK or is too deep as I seem to get stuck when i try and do "deeper" than 3 leves.

I can create a var and get just the policy and from there create another var and then grab the deeper level schedules, but is there a way to do it from a single query?

I'm thinking I'd need a select new and combine the two selects to be able to return the police name and the schedule name.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
<Config>
    <Policies>
        <Policy Number="3">
          <PolicyName>AD_EXCHANGE</PolicyName>
          <General>
            <PerformSnapshot>Enabled</PerformSnapshot>
            <DataClassification>Platinum</DataClassification>
          </General>
          <Clients>
            <Client Number="1">
              <ClientHostname>BORHOMBX</ClientHostname>
              <ClientHardware>Windows-x64</ClientHardware>
              <ClientOS>Windows</ClientOS>
              <ClientPriority>0</ClientPriority>
            </Client>
          </Clients>
          <Schedules>
            <Schedule Number="1">
              <ScheduleName>AD_PLATINUM_DAILY_FULL</ScheduleName>
              <ResidenceIsSLP>Yes</ResidenceIsSLP>
            </Schedule>
            <Schedule Number="2">
              <ScheduleName>AD_PLATINUM_MONTHLY_FULL</ScheduleName>
              <ResidenceIsSLP>Yes</ResidenceIsSLP>
            </Schedule>
          </Schedules>
        </Policy>
    </Policies>
</Config>
```

Comment: Did you try anything and get an error or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this:

```
var result= from e in doc.Decendants("Policy")
            from s in e.Decendants("Schedule")
            where s.Element("ResidenceIsSLP").Value=="No"
            select new {
                          PolicyName= (string)e.Element("PolicyName"),
                          ScheduleName= (string)s.Element("ScheduleName")
                       };
```

Using a double `from` you will get a Cartesian Product between the policies and schedules that belong to.

Answer (score 1):

I parsed the entire xml you posted using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("Policy").Select(x => new {
                number = (int)x.Attribute("Number"),
                name = (string)x.Element("PolicyName"),
                performSnapshot = (string)x.Descendants("PerformSnapshot").FirstOrDefault(),
                dataClassification = (string)x.Descendants("DataClassification").FirstOrDefault(),
                clients = x.Descendants("Client").Select(y => new {
                    number = (int)y.Attribute("Number"),
                    clientHostname = (string)y.Element("ClientHostname"),
                    clientHardware = (string)y.Element("ClientHardware"),
                    clientOS = (string)y.Element("ClientOS"),
                    clientPriority = (int)y.Element("ClientPriority"),
                }).ToList(),
                schedule = x.Descendants("Schedule").Select(y => new {
                    number = (int)y.Attribute("Number"),
                    scheduleName = (string)y.Element("ScheduleName"),
                    residenceIsSLP = (string)y.Element("ResidenceIsSLP")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```